# How can I duct through a new cabinet from a floor vent opening at the wall?

Tags: vent, ducts, bench

Got a window bench put in, but need a way to direct the air from the old baseboard vent register hole to out the front of the bench. NOt so sure a box store is going to have the proper vent duct parts I need in the correct shape. This guy online makes something exactly for it but it'll cost $72 shipped which is ridiculous: https://toekickductor.com/product/toe-ductor-baseboard-vent-kits/

Any help is appreciated. I'm not so sure I'll be able to cut a vent boot / trim, but maybe.

vent hole is about 14" x 2", register hole in front of bench is about 10" by 4"

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Why do you need a duct? Most bathroom vanities, for example, are wide open from a slot in the floor to the louver on the kick panel. Just close off the compartment by any convenient means and call it a day. Staple some cardboard in if that works.

And parts from a big box store should work just fine. A common 2x10 or whatever size duct could be laid right in place with an opening cut in the bottom for the floor vent and the flaps flipped outward to close the rest of the opening. I think you're thinking too hard. It's just air. :)

Comment: Hah, cardboard? Most definitely I am probably over thinking it. Got a link to an example duct piece you are referring to?

Comment: If (as it would appear) you are wasting the potential storage space in the "window bench" just put some holes in the front (trimmed however you like) and you are done. The whole thing is your "duct." If you were going to make the storage space useful, just put in a raised bottom (*i.e.* the "duct" becomes the space between the floor and a bottom board attached to the framing lumber, and whatever holes/louver you install on the front of that space.) Personally, I would never build a window bench/seat without making useable access to the storage space thus created - it's far too useful.

Comment: It’s usable space, sorry, photo is only middle section of window bench. There’s two other spaces , one to left and right of the middle section. Interior is open through to all 3 sections.

Comment: So no plans to add shelving or otherwise trim it out?